# Understanding IDA's netnodes

Tags: ida

What exactly is a Netnode? What are they used for and how can I manipulate them with IDC or the SDK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The online IDA SDK has an excellent description: https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/sdkdoc/netnode_8hpp.html

An IDA database is one large table of key/value pairs.
All keys associated with a single address together form a `netnode`.

There are two kinds of netnodes:

- related to addresses associated with the binary loaded in ida.
- for internal items, these are used to store structs, stack-frames, enums, scripts, etc.

These internal items usually have addresses which start with `0xFF0...`.
Because of this it can be a bit of a challenge to reverse engineer binaries which happen to use that address range.

A list of items which are stored in netnodes can be found in [netnode.hpp](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/sdkdoc/netnode_8hpp.html) and [nalt.hpp](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/sdkdoc/nalt_8hpp.html)